# How to select all div tags within a div tag with a class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
```

Here is an example of the code. I tried doing this

```
.wrapper > div {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: Use like .wrapper div {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
}   Dont use '>' operator, it selects the immediate first child only

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead

```
.wrapper div {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Welcome @ErickMartinezSr.

Answer (score 0):

**div** must be enclosed within the **wrapper** class and remove **>** in your css.

This one works.

```css
.wrapper div {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So if you remove the > does it still select all the div's in the wrapper?

Comment: Yes, using `>` selects the direct children while using using space selects all elements (in your case is `div`) under root element